# Disable the toolbar module in install profile

Tags: drush

How do I disable the toolbar module in my make file / profile info / install file?

Comment: Just don't have a dependency on it, and it won't be enabled. You can't have a "negative dependency" on a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an install file perspective, you can use a combination of [`module_exists`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_exists/7) and [`module_disable`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7), in an implementation of [`hook_enable`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7).

*Example:*

```
function MYMODULE_enable() {
  if (module_exists('toolbar') {
    module_disable('toolbar');
  }
}
```

Module enabling/disabling isn't within the scope of a make file, so that won't work.

Lastly, as far as I'm aware, if a module is not declared as a dependency of a profile, the it won't be enabled.  If I'm mistaken, you can still use the code shown above to disable the module (although I can't 100% confirm where to put it, as I've never made an install profile).